# Función que lee un array en el estado de react, no coge el último item añadido de este

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Este es un problema que me acuerdo que me ocurrió el año pasado y no consigo acordarme como lo solucioné. Estoy seguro que es algo relativamente sencillo pero no acabo de sacar como solucionarlo.

Básicamente tengo una función que añade un objeto al estado del componente de React. "El problema" es que dentro de la  misma función a continuación tengo una llamada a una API Rest, que envía el objeto entero que se encuentra en el estado recientemente actualizado (se que no es codigo limpio juntar dos cosas diferentes en una misma función, pero no se me ocurre como hacer que una form en react dispare dos funciones diferentes que responden a un evento onClick a la vez, con lo cual tengo ambas cosas en la misma función).

Básicamente cuando consulto la Base de datos dónde debería estar el objeto actualizado, siempre le falta el último item añadido.

Esta es la función:

```js
state = {
        new_site: "",
        user_sites: [],
    }

addSite = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let itemsCounter = this.state.user_sites.length +1;
        // LOCAL:
        const newSite = this.state.new_site;
        Geocode.fromAddress(newSite).then(
            response => {
                const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;

                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    user_sites: [{ "name": newSite, "id": itemsCounter, coordinates: [lat, lng] }, ...prevState.user_sites]
                }))
                console.log(this.state.user_sites)
            },
            error => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        );
        // API REST
        axios.patch('https://c6t66n8v7.execute-api...', {
            email: this.state.current_user,
            sites: this.state.user_sites,
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log('Sitio añadido en bbdd')
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        
    }
    
 render(){
 
     return (
     <Container className="add-container">
                                <Form onSubmit={this.addSite}>
                                    <h4>Añade un sitio </h4>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Form.Control type="text" onChange={this.onChangeNewSite} value={this.state.new_site} placeholder="ejemplo: Madrid, New York...etc" />
                                    </Row>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" variant="success">Añadir</Button>
                                    </Row>

                                </Form>
                            </Container>
     )
 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta situacion me ha pasado tambien y es el resultado de los  tiempos de ejecucion de los procesos asincronos, los cuales tu no tienes control de cuando terminan(Latency y tiempo de ejecucion en el lado del servidor). La solucion a tu problema es crear lo que se conoce como Chain of Promises (Cadena de promesas.).

Codigo:

```
addSite = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let itemsCounter = this.state.user_sites.length +1;
    // LOCAL:
    const newSite = this.state.new_site;
    Geocode.fromAddress(newSite).then(
        response => {
            const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;

            this.setState(prevState => ({
                user_sites: [{ "name": newSite, "id": itemsCounter, coordinates: [lat, `lng] }, ...prevState.user_sites]`
            }))
            // Yo prefiero pasar los valores como parametros y eliminar la dependencia con el state
            actualizarApi();
            console.log(this.state.user_sites)
        },
        error => {
            console.error(error);
        }
    );      

}

    actualizarApi = () => {

 // API REST
        axios.patch('https://c6t66n8v7.execute-api...', {
            email: this.state.current_user,
            sites: this.state.user_sites,
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log('Sitio añadido en bbdd')
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```